# Terminate for loop for some samples which are not in input vector

Tags: matlab

I have a row vector :

```
x=[6673 6954 6960 7130 7167 7352 7565 7600 7793 7823 7992 8113 8193 8202 8410 8649 8806 9081 9284 9462 9657 9738 9913 10126 10333 10558 10665 10946];
```

I want to get first value of x, then value after x(1)+60 that is 6954, then value 6954+60 that is 7130 (skipping all those values which come within (particular value + 60).

I want to have output like:

```
y= [6673 6954 7130 7565 7793 7992 8113 8193 8410 8649 8806 9081 9284 9462 9657 9738 9913 10126 10333 10558 10665 10946]
```

The value 6960 is skipped as it comes under 6954+60=7014, likewise 7167 is skipped as it comes under 7130+60=7190 and so on.

This is what I have tried so far but couldn't get desired result.

```
clear
clc
x=[6673 6954 6960 7130 7167 7352 7565 7600 7793 7823 7992 8113 8193 8202 8410 8649 8806 9081 9284 9462 9657 9738 9913 10126 10333 10558 10665 10946];

x1=x(1)-1:x(end)+60;
for i=1:length(x)  
y1(:,i)=find(x(i)==x1)
end

for i=1:25

    y=x1(y1(i))
    y(y+60)=0

    if length(y)<x(i+1)
        y2(:,i)=x1(y1(i))
    else
        y2(:,i)=x1(y1(i+1))
    end

end
 y(y==0) = [];
```

Comment: What happened to `7352`? Why did that get skipped?

Comment: Consider rephrase your question. Need better description!

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. It is not skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
x([true, diff(x) > 60])
```

---

but what if `x` is like this:

```
x = [1 50 100];
```

do you want an output of `[1]` or `[1, 100]`?

Comment: I want an output of [1,100]

Comment: +1 I was about to write the same, but was looking for what happend with 7352 ;)

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal Well my solution won't give you that, and your question does not specify that. So are you sure this is right? Or do you want a new answer that will output `[1,100]`?

Comment: @ Dan. Last thing I would ask is that how can I get the second values from the blocks which are within (+60). That is 6960 instead of 6954, 7167 instead of 7130 and so on. but getting 6673 , 7352, etc as it is, as they do not come under (+60).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to do.

but do something like:

```
dx = diff(x);
while any(dx < 60)
    ib1 = find(dx<60,1,'first')+1;
    x(ib1) = [];
    dx = diff(x);
end
```

This solution is a little more complicated, but also more robust.

Comment: this more or less the same like @Dan's solution, but much more complicated.

Comment: @thewaywewalk this is not the same, this will remove elements so that the gaps are all greater than 60 in the end rather than mine which removes all elements less than 60 in the beginning. This does not deserve a down vote imo

Comment: @Dan Well, the main idea was to evaluate `diff(x)` - and while you are just indexing the input with the result of `diff(x) > 60` - this answer deletes all elements `diff(x) < 60` - and also step by step in an unnecessary loop. For my opinion it's the same approach, without any improvement. I would undo the downvote (would require an edit) - if you tell whats really different and better. ;)

Comment: @Dan I see the point with the last element, but you could fix that easily in your answer as well. I'll undo the downvote as soon as I'm able to do it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk it's not about the last element, it's any in the middle. For example `x =[1,50,100,150,200];` mine will return `1` where this answer returns `[1,100,200]`. The question asks for mine but the OP mentioned in a comment that this is actually what is required. You can undo your down vote but making your own trivial edit.

Comment: @Dan. You're right, that case didn't seemed to be very important to me. But you're right, it's the more robust approach. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: ???  Index of element to remove exceeds matrix dimensions.
 This is the error which appeared while executing your commands.

Comment: That should not happen. Can you post size(x) and size(dx)?